# Using Generic in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I am new to iOS development . I wanted to create a dictionary which is looks like

```
var userInformation: UserInformation = UserInformation()
var genericDictionary: Dictionary<Int,userInformation> = [Int:userInformation]()
```

here ,userInformation is an object of  UserInformation  class .

```
class UserInformation{
var name:String?
var phonenumber:String?
init(_ name:String ,_phoneNumber:String){
   self.name = name
   self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
}
```

and lastly i tried `genericDictionary.append()`. i wanted to store name and phone number here. i don't know how it works!

i tried , but it shows various kinds of error. is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in declaration of `dictionary` with value type you are specifying the object that you have created instead of its type, means it should be `UserInformation` class type instead of instance of it `userInformation`. Try like this way.

```
var genericDictionary = [Int:UserInformation]()
```

**Edit:** With latest edit of your question I thin'k you are looking for `array` not `dictionary`, if it is true try like this way.

```
var array = [UserInformation]()
array.append(userInformation)
```

Comment: Check the edited answer once if you are looking for array not dictionary.

Comment: i rewrite my code but now i want to add value in genericDictionary .How do i do it ?

Comment: @MituVinci If you are looking for to add simply object then you are looking for array not dictionary check my edited answer and create array instead of dictionary and then append object in array.

Comment: i changed my code . it is appending now but when i print the array it shows [UserInformationViewController.UserInformation,UserInformationViewController.UserInformation,..........]

Comment: @MituVinci It's obvious if you print array of custom object it will print like that check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350101/how-to-print-value-of-object-in-an-array-in-swift-not-its-location if you want print property value and add description property

Answer (score 1):

Do like this :

```
var genericDictionary : [Int : UserInformation] = [:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the dictionary using a variable instead of the class. Instead of `userInformation`, you need to use `UserInformation` like this:

```
var genericDictionary: Dictionary<Int,UserInformation> = [Int:UserInformation]()
```